# Sort string-matrix [[a, b, c], ...] by a, -c, b, maintaining order?

Tags: python, string, sorting, multidimensional-array

I have a list of lists of three strings in Python, e.g.,

```
m = [['pig', 'quartz', '1'], ['pork', 'nails', '1'], ...]
```

and I want to sort it by index 0, then by index 2 in reverse order, then by index 1. At each step in the sort I'd like to maintain the order imposed by the other columns. For instance,

```
pork       barn         4
pork       barn2        4
pork       nails        1
pig        quartz       1
quinoa     pail         1
quinoa     quatern      1
quail      quatern      1
radish     barn         1
radish     barn2        1
radish     inbox        3
radish     snow         1
```

would become:

```
pig        quartz       1
pork       barn         4
pork       barn2        4
pork       nails        1
quail      quatern      1
quinoa     pail         1
quinoa     quatern      1
radish     inbox        3    <-
radish     barn         1
radish     barn2        1
radish     snow         1
```

that is, sort by the first column, then within each group of 1st columns (pig, pork, quail, ...), sort by the third column reversed, then within each group of 1st-column-3rd-column ((pig, 1), (pork, 4), (pork, 1), ...), sort by the second column.

How can I do this nicely? Conceptually, if `operator.itemgetter()` could encode sort order along with index, I would want something like `m.sort(key=operator.itemgetter(0, -2, 1))`.

Comment: Is the third item always an integer?

Comment: @Avaris: Yes, it's always a string containing an int.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a custom comparison function:

```
def compare_triples(a, b):
    ret=cmp(a[0], b[0])
    if ret: return ret
    ret=cmp(b[2], a[2])
    if ret: return ret
    return cmp(a[1], b[1])

for i in m: print i
print "-" * 79
m2=sorted(m, cmp=compare_triples)
for i in m2: print i
```

The compare function is not optimal and might be rewritten as:

```
def compare_triples(a, b):
    return cmp((a[0], b[2], a[1]), (b[0], a[2], b[1]))
```

As others have pointed out this will work too:

```
def sort_key(a):
    return a[0], -int(a[2]), a[1]

for i in sorted(m, key=sort_key): print i
```

Comment: That while loop is the wrong way to do it. Why wouldn't you just do `ret=cmp(); if ret != 0: return ret`?

Comment: This is the most generic solution, given that all inputs are _strings_.

Comment: Yeah this felt clumsy while writing it, I've adjusted the code.

Answer (score 4):

```
def key(item):
    return item[0], -int(item[2]), item[1]
m.sort(key = key)
```

PS. The `cmp` keyword argument has been [removed from Python3](http://docs.python.org/release/3.0.1/whatsnew/3.0.html#ordering-comparisons). For future compatibility you may wish to stick with `key`.

Answer (score 2):

I would try something like this:

```
def sort_key(a, b, c):
   return (a, -int(c) , b)           

m.sort(key = lambda row: sort_key(*row))
```

Comment: The problem is that all three columns are strings.

Comment: Sorry, updated, but if you need more generic thing, will have to use `cmp` instead. In any case, I'd rather use what unutbu says.